# Entity Famework: Select in Linq Problems with Date formats

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Hi i have this code in a controller, this works fine converting the date format of **Fecha** attribute

```
var com = db.Comentario
               .Where(co => co.IdProducto == id)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Fecha)
               .Skip((int)offset)
               .Take(2)
               .ToList()
               .Select(c => new {
                   c.Id,
                   Usuario = new {
                       c.Usuario.Nombre,
                       c.Usuario.Apellidos,
                       c.Usuario.Avatar,
                       c.Usuario.Nickname
                   },
                   c.Contenido,
                   Fecha = c.Fecha.ToShortDateString(), //it works fine
                   R = c.IdEstado == 1 ? false : true
               });
```

but... the problem is in the other controller

```
        db.Comentario.Add(com);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var resp = db.Comentario
                .Where(c => c.Id == com.Id)
                .Select(c => new {
                    c.Id,
                    Usuario = new {
                        c.Usuario.Nombre,
                        c.Usuario.Apellidos,
                        c.Usuario.Avatar,
                        c.Usuario.Nickname
                    },
                    c.Contenido,
                    Fecha = c.Fecha.ToShortDateString(),//the problem is here
                    R = c.IdEstado == 1 ? false : true
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here i insert to the database a **Comentario** object and i want to return that object in a JSON result, but got this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I cant understand why the code fails, if both are the same code.
Thanks

Comment: Behind the scenes, these pieces of code get parsed and handled differently.  The first piece of code executes a query against the DB after the `Take()` `ToList()` operations, and then you are performing a `Select` on the resulting `List` of items.  At that point, you are using Linq against an enumerable.

In the second code set, everything before `FirstOrDefault` gets translated as SQL, and Linq to Entities doesn't know what to do with `ToShortDateString()` because it has no translation for that.

Comment: Don't format the date in the query. Let the UI decide how to display a date. You're not going to tack `ToShortDateString()` to each date you'll send to the UI, are you?

Comment: yeah, but when i send date without format i got that "\Date(321654879)/", and i suppose that is a unix date, but when i convert that, i get a incorrect date

Comment: Yes that's how JSON serialization does it by default. I didn't say it's trivial, but still, it is the way to go. Sometimes you want to display dates with time component, sometimes without, or you want to edit them in a data picker that expects a date. Or you want the client culture decide  how the date is displayed! Moment.js is a great help here.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't the same... As soon as you call `.ToList()`, you're executing your query against the underlying data store.

```
var com = db.Comentario
               .Where(co => co.IdProducto == id)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Fecha)
               .Skip((int)offset)
               .Take(2)
               .ToList() // <<< Your query is being executed here
```

Everything above is translated into SQL by EntityFramework with ease... Entity Framework retrieves that data for you and after you've called `ToList()` the data is stored in memory, meaning the data has been retrieved and you're no longer querying data that's stored on a database, but data that's already been fetched.

Compare that to your second example...

```
    var resp = db.Comentario
            .Where(c => c.Id == com.Id)
            .Select(c => new {   // <<< Here you're still querying the
                c.Id,            //     database, nothing has been received / executed yet.
                Usuario = new {
                    c.Usuario.Nombre,
                    c.Usuario.Apellidos,
                    c.Usuario.Avatar,
                    c.Usuario.Nickname
                },
                c.Contenido,
                Fecha = c.Fecha.ToShortDateString(),
```

EntityFramework hasn't fetched the data yet, it's attempting to translate your query into SQL, but you can't translate `ToShortDateString()` to SQL. What you need to do is execute your query like you've done earlier with `ToList()` right in between the `Where(...)` and `Select(...)` clauses.

Comment: I tried puting **ToList()** between Where and Select clauses, but i got that error, **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** in this line: **.Select(c =&gt; new {**

Comment: Run through your method using breakpoints. I have a feeling that your `c.Fecha` property is null

Comment: this is the results, the **Fecha** property is not null, [Image](http://i.imgur.com/q3PefzF.png)

Comment: Usario is the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Good news guys, I found a solution, buy i'm not sure if this is the best way.

```
      var resp = db.Comentario
                .Include(u=>u.Usuario) // with this Usuario is no longer null
                .Where(c => c.Id == com.Id && c.IdEstado != 3)
                .ToList()
                .Select(c => new {
                    c.Id,
                    Usuario = new {
                        c.Usuario.Nombre,
                        c.Usuario.Apellidos,
                        c.Usuario.Avatar,
                        c.Usuario.Nickname
                    },
                    c.Contenido,
                    Fecha = c.Fecha.ToShortDateString(),
                    R = c.IdEstado == 1 ? false : true
                });
```

And i removed **FirstOrDefault()**, and i put **ToList()** between Where and Select clauses

This was my solution
Thanks :D